# Quick Question about FontAwesome in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

So I'm learning Reactjs and i want to use FontAwesome in my project. But i have 1 problem.
In their documentation, it said:

```
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

**fab** : which represents all of the brand icons in @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons. So any of the brand icons in that package may be referenced by icon name as a string anywhere else in our app. For example: "apple", "microsoft", or "google".

**faCheckSquare and faCoffee** : Adding each of these icons individually allows us to refer to them throughout our app by their icon string names, "check-square" and "coffee", respectively.

---

So i want to know which will represent all solid-svg-icons?

If i need 20 icons in my component, then i will have to write all 20 faCheckQuare, faCoffe, ... right?
Please tell me if there is any way better than this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can import them all.

```
import * as SvgIcons from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

and then start using them.

```
SvgIcons.faCheckSquare
SvgIcons.faCoffee 
// etc ...
```

if anything else you need to know please comment.

Comment: it works but i still have to list every icon in `library.add()` like this `library.add(SvgIcons.faCoffee)`.
anyway, i found the keyword for solid icons. It's 'fas.
Thanks for your help